# Invalid use of non-static member function with header files

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

```
#define MYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/home/sulli313/Project4/Film.h"

void Film::showList(){
    std::cout << "\n-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "         Query Application         " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " 1 All letter name actors" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " 2 First # PG-13 and Above" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " 3 All active/inactive users by store" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " 4 Actor Movie titles and ids" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1 Exit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">> Enter your choice:" << std::endl;
}
void Film::showOne(){
mysqlpp::Connection myDB("cse278F2022", "localhost", "cse278F2022",
            "raspberrySeltzer");
    // Create a query
    mysqlpp::Query query = myDB.query();
    std::cout << "Please enter a Letter A-Z!" << std::endl;
    std::string letter;
    std::cin >> letter;
        ///////////////////////////////////Do this part/////////////////////////////////////////////
    //if(letter)

    query << "SELECT first_name, last_name "
          << "FROM actor " 
          << "WHERE first_name " 
          << "LIKE '" + letter + "%'";
       //     << "WHERE code = \"IST\"";

    query.parse();
    mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult result = query.store();

    std::cout << "Here is your selection!\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--First/Last Names of Actors Whos First ";
    std::cout << "Name Stars With " + letter + "--\n" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(12) << "First Name" << 
    std::setw(10) << "Last Name" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    for (const auto & row : result) {  
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(12) << row[0].c_str();
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << row[1] << std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout << "\n" << "to continue, press enter..." << std::endl;
    showList();
}

void Film::showTwo(){
    mysqlpp::Connection myDB("cse278F2022", "localhost", "cse278F2022",
            "raspberrySeltzer");

    //Selecting the second option's query
    std::cout << "Please type a limit 1-30!" << std::endl;
    std::string limit;
    std::cin >> limit;
    
    
    mysqlpp::Query query = myDB.query();
    query << "SELECT title " 
          << "FROM film " 
          << "WHERE rating = 'PG-13' " 
          << "OR rating = 'R' " 
          << "OR rating = 'NC-17' " 
          << "LIMIT " + limit + " ";
    query.parse();
    mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult result = query.store();

    std::cout << "Here is your selection!\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--First "+ limit +" Titles PG-13 to NC-17--\n" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::left <<std::setw(20)<< "Title" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------" <<std::endl;
    
    for (const auto & row : result) {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << row[0].c_str()<< std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout << "\n" << "to continue, press enter..." << std::endl;
    showList();
}

void Film::showThree(){
    mysqlpp::Connection myDB("cse278F2022", "localhost", "cse278F2022",
            "raspberrySeltzer");

    //bind variable
    std::cout << "Please type 1 for active and 0 for inactive!" << std::endl;
    std::string active;
    std::cin >> active;
    if(active != "1" && active != "0"){
        std::cout << "Wrong!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please type 1 for active and 0 for inactive!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> active;
    }

    //Selecting the second option's query
    mysqlpp::Query query = myDB.query();
    query << "SELECT Count(*) "
          << "FROM customer "
          << "WHERE active = '"+ active + "' "
          << "GROUP BY store_id";
    query.parse();
    mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult result = query.store();
    std::cout << "Here is your selection!\n" << std::endl;
    if(active == "1"){
    std::cout << "--Count of All Active Users Grouped by Store Id--\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left <<std::setw(20)<< "Active User Ids" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------" <<std::endl;
    } else {
    std::cout << "--Count of All Inactive Users Grouped by Store Id--\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left <<std::setw(20)<< "Inactive User Ids" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------" <<std::endl;
    }
    
    
    for (const auto & row : result) {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << row[0].c_str()<< std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout << "\n" << "to continue, press enter..." << std::endl;
    showList();
}

void Film::showFour(){
    mysqlpp::Connection myDB("cse278F2022", "localhost", "cse278F2022",
            "raspberrySeltzer");

    //bind variable
    std::cout << "Please type an actor id that is 1-200!" << std::endl;
    std::string act_id;
    std::cin >> act_id;


    //Selecting the second option's query
    mysqlpp::Query query = myDB.query();
    query << "SELECT film.title, film.film_id, film_actor.actor_id "
          << "FROM film, film_actor "
          << "WHERE film_actor.actor_id = "+ act_id +" "
          << "GROUP BY title "
          << "LIMIT 20";
    query.parse();
    mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult result = query.store();
    std::cout << "Here is your selection!\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--First 20 Titles and IDs of Actor Id 25--\n" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::left <<std::setw(22)<< "Title" << 
                    std::setw(10)<< "Film_id" << std::setw(0)<<"Actor_id" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------" <<std::endl;
    
    for (const auto & row : result) {
        std::cout << std::left<<std::setw(22)<< row[0].c_str() << std::setw(10) << row[1] << std::setw(0) << row[2].c_str() << std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout << "\n" << "to continue, press enter..." << std::endl;
    showList();
}
```

```
#ifndef FILM_H
#define FILM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Film {
    
public:
    void showList();
    void showOne();
    void showTwo();
    void showThree();
    void showFour();

private:

};

#endif
```

```
// Copyright
// Purpose: Project 4
// Date 11/25/2022
// Author: Colton Sullivan
#define MYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include "/home/sulli313/Project4/Film.h"

int main() {
   int choice;
   showList();

   std::cin >> choice;
    
   if (choice == -1) {
      std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
   }
   while (choice != -1) {
   while ( choice >  4 || choice < -1 || choice == 0 ) {
      std::cout << "The wrong choice!!!" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "to continue, press enter...";
      showList();
      std::cin >> choice;
   }
   if ( choice == 1 ) {
      showOne();
   }
   if ( choice == 2 ) {
      showTwo;
   }
   if ( choice == 3 ) {
      showThree;
   }
   if ( choice == 4 ) {
      showFour;
   }
      std::cin >> choice;
      if ( choice == -1 ) {
      std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

When trying to switch the original program to object oriented programming, I ran into the problem of the error "Invalid use of non-static member function" popping up for the showOne, showTwo, showThree, showFour and showList functions.

If there is a way to access the functions that are created in the Film.cpp/Film.h files and use them in the QueryApp.cpp file to run that as the main, please let me know.

I have tried switching it from Film::showOne, Film::showTwo...etc to showOne(); and Film::showOne(); but either the same Invalid use of non-static member function error will show or it will say that it has not be declared in this scope.

Comment: This is my second question on stack so please be kind, still getting used to how this all works

Comment: You're trying to convert this to object oriented programming. Where do you create a `Film` object?

Comment: You should create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note the "minimal" part.

Comment: Also, as a privacy note, I hope that you haven't included an actual password you use in this source code. Especially since that code doesn't appear to be particularly related to anything you're having issues with.

Comment: Please include the full error message in your [mre]

Comment: Yes there is, you need to declare a film object. `int main() { Film film; ... film.showOne(); ... }`

Comment: Building QUERY with concatenation of user-string is risky, see [exploits of a mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `showSomething()` functions are all member functions of the `Film` type. In particular, because they are not marked as [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), they are *non-static member functions*. That means they operate on an *instance* of `Film`:

```
class C {
  public:
    void a(); // <- non-static member function
    static void b(); // <- static member function
};

void foo() {
  C::b(); // okay, doesn't need an object
  C::a(); // not okay, needs an object
  C object; // instance of C
  object.a(); // okay
  object.b(); // also okay
}
```

Typically you would give your object some state information or it raises the question why you have a non-static member function to begin with. If you don't need state, make them free functions (i.e., functions that are not member functions) or make them `static`.

In your case, I suppose it would be helpful to create a database connection in your `Film`'s [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) so you can use the database member in all the functions that need a database connection to function.
Something like this:

```
class Film {
  private:
    mysqlpp::Connection myDB;
  public:
    Film() : myDB("x", "localhost", "y", "z") {}
    // ...
};
```